# value of OPEN_MAX

Tags: posix, portability

What is the value of `OPEN_MAX` on various platforms?

I know that the dynamic limit for the number of open file descriptors can be retrieved through `sysconf (_SC_OPEN_MAX)`, `getdtablesize ()`, or `getrlimit (NOFILE, ...)`. Nonetheless, I want to know how large I can choose file descriptors in the simplest possible case.

When I look at `<limits.h>` on my system, I only ever get the value for that system.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN_MAX is defined in `<limits.h>`:

| Operating system | Value |
| --- | --- |
| AIX ≥ 5.2 | 65534 |
| AIX < 5.2 | 32767 |
| macOS | 10240 |
| Interix | 1024 |
| Linux, Solaris, Cygwin | 256 |
| Minix | 255 |
| BeOS, Haiku, NetBSD | 128 |
| FreeBSD, OpenBSD, OSF/1 | 64 |
| HP-UX | 60 |
| native Windows | 32 |
| IRIX | 20 |